# A Point-free probability theory?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ho.history-overview

I must confess I hardly know anything about probability theory. Still, I'm interested in the following: Much like point-free topology, where one basically replaces topological spaces by their locales of open sets, I figured there is a way to do something similar with $\sigma$-algebras and with probability spaces.

> Any thoughts on that? Does somebody know, whether this has been studied
>   before?

Here are some more thoughts: I suppose a problem is how to recover the sample space $\Omega$ from a point-free probability space, as there is a no guarantee that there is an injection $\Omega \to \sigma$ from the sample space to the $\sigma$-algebra of a probability space. I wonder, how important it is to have a sample space at all. I (think I) know, that probability theory is actually about random variables, but do we really need a sample space to talk about those? Also, considering that there is no obvious notion of a morphism between probability spaces, maybe there are other objects we should look at?

*(I asked this question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413444/pointfree-probability-theory) and a user suggested to ask this on MO. I studied mathematics for about a year in university, so my background is not actually that sophisticated. I only know a little bit category theory, analysis and linear algebra)*

Comment: It is good etiquette to wait a reasonable amount of time before cross-posting from MSE to here (say a week, you didn't even wait for an hour) and to cross-link the question, so as to avoid double efforts. You already had a reply on MSE, by the way.

Comment: The standard point-free version of measure theory is to replace the algebraa of measurable sets by an abstract boolean algebra and the measure by a suitable function thereon.  A good place to read about this and its motivation is the series of books by Fremlin, many of which are readily available online.

Comment: @priel I assume you are referring to volume 3. It is definitely interesting and worth looking into, but it's measure theory not exactly probability theory. I was under the impression, that concepts like "random variables" are special to probability theory. Still, thank you for this information. There seem to be many useful ideas there.

Comment: There is also "Topological Riesz Spaces and Measure Theory" which discusses the classical spaces of random variables in this context.

Comment: @priel Ah, yes I missed that one and you seem to be right. I can't say more than that since the material is currently impenetrable to me. (maybe asking this question $\uparrow$ now wasn't the best idea)

Comment: @Marco Golla, the poster's misbehavior is my fault, as I recommended him to post here. Also, the answer on MSE is quite unrelated to the question.

Stefan Perko, asking a question was not a bad idea. There are many people (including me) who are also interested in an answer.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you for very much for clarifying both issues. I appreciate it.

Comment: Doing probability theory on pointfree Boolean algebras has a long history. See the survey [On the axiomatic treatment of probability](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm3/cm3116.pdf) by Jerzy Łoś, *Colloquium Mathematicae.* Vol. 2. No. 3. 1955.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Point-free probability theory, is treated in Kappos's book: Probability algebras and Stochastic spaces. Academic Press, 1969.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think the accepted answer is a complete one. To be honest there is no such a pointless theory as far as I know.

And I actually have read the book [Kappos] which could be viewed as a continution/smaller version of [Grenander](The dates is earlier also). The idea of using Markov transition kernel as morphisms between spaces is not quite extendible as we could see later in [Cencov]'s comprehensive treatment. As discussed in [Rota] a probability theory that is pointless is not available at the time he wrote down the paper (1998 Fubini talk), and as far as I concern the pointless notion that makes use of a locale is not well addressed in terms of "stochastic spaces". They provided algebraic structures but never a complete formal category definitions and their applications are rare if any.

Another attempt in this direction is to study the stochastic processes as a geometric object directly, which I think is more productive than the pure algebraic way. This approach dates back to the H.Cramer's approach of treating stochastic processes as a curve in Hilbert space.

The point of proposing a pointless probability theory is to discover some properties that are not clear when atoms/points are involved (yes it is also of categorical theoretic interest as well...but less). Since the geometric feature is revealed pretty well by using diffeomorphism flows over a space/group, the pointless theory itself attracts less interest now. (That is how I feel)

**Reference**

[Kappos]Kappos, Demetrios A. Probability algebras and stochastic spaces. Vol. 7. Academic Press, 2014.

[Cencov]Cencov, Nikolai Nikolaevich. Statistical decision rules and optimal inference. No. 53. American Mathematical Soc., 2000.

[Rota]Rota, G-C. "Twelve problems in probability no one likes to bring up." Algebraic combinatorics and computer science. Springer Milan, 2001. 57-93.

[Grenander]Grenander, Ulf. Probabilities on algebraic structures. Courier Corporation, 2008.

Comment: "I do not think the accepted answer is a complete one." - I did not expect anyone to give a 'complete' answer. I was okay with an answer like that after almost a year of this question being formally unanswered.

Comment: Regardless, thank you for your input as well. - Arguably, pointfree "something" is not an algebraic thing. It is actually *dual* to something algebraic (cf. the definition of the category of locales) and therefore rather geometric. Or so is my very rough understanding of this issue.

Comment: @StefanPerko As I understood the reference he pointed out is not even close to point-free theory that you want, Gerenander's book will be a better reference than that one.

Comment: Well, I don't have access to that book. From the ToC it seems it is more about replacing the boolean algebra ($\sigma$-algebra standin) with something else entirely. This *may* be interesting, but I myself right now don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly related... Caratheodory's book on measure and integration without points ...

Carathéodory, C. *Mass und Integral und ihre Algebraisierung.* (1956)

translated

Carathéodory, C. *Algebraic theory of measure and integration.* (1963) 
Translated from the German by F. E. J. Linton